# Scanf in while loop for getting matrix input

Tags: c, matrix, while-loop, scanf, newline

Can anyone explain how the below mentioned `scanf` part will execute in `while` loop for getting matrix input without boundary size in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[10000];
    int a[100][100], rows = 0, cols = 0;
    while (scanf("%[^\n]\n", s) == 1) {
        char *num = strtok(s, " ");
        int val = 0;
        while (num != NULL) {
            a[rows][val++] = atoi(num);
            num = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        rows++;
        cols = val;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n)
    }
}
```

Comment: "How the … `scanf()` part will execute in [the] `while` loop" — Badly: see [What is the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168)  It would be far safer to use `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) to read the lines of data than to try using `scanf()` to do so. You could read the newline accurately using `%c` (or even `%*c`) instead of embedding the trailing newline in the format string. You also don't know how many values are initialized in each row of the matrix. You don't reset `cols` to zero at the end of a line of input. Problems!

Comment: Your code is also prone to buffer overflow.

Comment: @SupportUkraine — looking at the code again in the morning light, I agree.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, my personal opinion is that if you find yourself using `%[…]` with `scanf`, and especially if you're using it in an attempt to read whole lines, this is a clear indication that it's time to [learn how to use something better than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-to-parse-input-instead-of-scanf).

Answer (score 1):

> how the below mentioned scanf part will execute ...

`scanf("%[^\n]\n",s)` weakly attempts to read a *line* of input.

Code then uses `strtok()` to find tokens which are then parsed with `atoi()`.

Code contains weaknesses.

**Incorrect reading a a *line* of user input**

`"%[^\n]"` fails if the first character is `'\n'`. Else it reads an unlimited number of non-`'\n'` characters into `s`, then appending a *null character*.  `"\n"` then reads in, and discards, 0 to an unlimited number of white-spaces including `'\n'`, `' '`, etc.

`while(scanf("%[^\n]\n",s)==1){` will stop the loop if the first line is only `"\n"`, but will silently consume `"\n"` otherwise.  Lacking a *width*, it it worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Perhaps `scanf("%9999[^\n]%c", s, &char_sentinel) >= 1`, yet far better to use `fgets()` here.

```
// Basic alternative
while (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
```

**10000 - that's a long line**

For 100 `int` in a line, I'd expect a worse case of 11 `char` (e.g. "-2147483647") and a spacer so 12*100 + an `'\n'` and `'\0'`.  Being generous, how about a worse case line twice that or `char s[(12*100+2)*2];`?

**Too many columns or rows break code**

`a[rows][val++]=atoi(num);` is also prone to buffer overflow as `row, col` may exceed valid range [0...99] resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB).

**No detection for uneven amount of columns**

The number of columns per row may vary.  The final printing `cols` only reflects the last row.

**Integer conversion woes**

`atoi(num)` lacks no conversion and overflow detection.  Rather than `strtok()`, `atoi()`, use `strtol()` to march down the line of text and detect problems.

**Limited size**

Code only handles a matrix up to 100 columns and 100 rows.  Code uses excessive sized buffers.  More advanced code would be more flexible. (not shown below)

**Some improvement ideas**

After reading a line ...

```
if (rows >= 100) {
  break; // TBD code to handle excessive rows
} 
char *str = s;
int column = 0;

while (*str) {
  if (column >= 100) {
    break; // TBD code to handle excessive columns
  } 
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long number = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
  // If no conversion or out-of-range ...
  if (str == endptr || errno || number < INT_MIN || number > INT_MAX) {
    break; // Handle errors in some fashion
  }
  a[rows][column++] = (int) number;
  str = endptr; // Start where prior conversion left off.
}
if (row == 0) {
  cols = column;
} else if (cols != column) {
  ; // Handle column mis-match
}
row++;
```

Comment: You might want to initialize the matrix to `0` in case all rows do not have the same number of columns.

Comment: @chqrlie Good point.  I'd rather error out, as in sample code, when column count is uneven.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @chux, it is much better to read the file one line at a time and parse the line with `strtol()` or some other safe method.

Also note that the final nested loops enumerate the cols first, then the rows so the matrix is output transposed. This might not be intended.

Here is an alternative using `sscanf()` to parse the line, displaying the matrix as it is entered:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[10000];
    int a[100][100] = { 0 };
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;

    while (rows < 100 && fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
        int col = 0, pos = 0, len;
        while (col < 100 && sscanf(s + pos, "%d%n", &s[rows][col], &len) == 1) {
            pos += len;
            col++;
        }
        if (cols < col)
            cols = col;
        rows++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: of course! answer amended and got rid of `<string.h>`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: There seems to be fewer and fewer votes on the [c] tag... Are C aficionados leaving SO? Where can we find actual stats?

Comment: Unknown to me on both questions.